# Simple PHP Comparison

Tags: php, google-maps

I've been staring at the screen to long today and just cannot seem to understand why this if statement doesnt seem to work. The Google Distance API outputs a value and km i.e. 17.8 km and eDistance outputs 50.

```
                            if(distanceGoogle("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?key=AIzaSyCd8iWEixVcMXRv3qQretshh33duoJ_YT8&address=http://example.co.uk&origins=$eventPostcode&destinations=$Postalcode&mode=$ModeSelected&language=en-EN&sensor=false") <= $eDistance){

                                ?>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(window).load(function(){
                                        $('#eventModal').modal('show');
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <?php
                                $ui->setAttribute('eventnotify', $eventPostcode);
                            } else {

                                //Further than distance criteria

                            }
```

This should only carry out the procedure (loading modal) when the distance calculated by Google is over the eDistance (50), however this is simply not the case. Probably a very silly mistake somewhere!

Comment: No, you actually have it set to only carry out when it is less than or equal to $eDistance...

Comment: @Devon Thats the desired function - it will display all events within 50 miles radius

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see your `<=` should be `>=` so currently your code runs if Google Distance returns less than or equal to 50 not greater than or equal to 50. So your code should be:

```
if(distanceGoogle("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?key=AIzaSyCd8iWEixVcMXRv3qQretshh33duoJ_YT8&address=http://example.co.uk&origins=$eventPostcode&destinations=$Postalcode&mode=$ModeSelected&language=en-EN&sensor=false") >= $eDistance){

?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){
        $('#eventModal').modal('show');
    });
    </script>
<?php

$ui->setAttribute('eventnotify', $eventPostcode);
} else {

    //Further than distance criteria

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it is the desired function that all events are shown within 50 mile radius and not over that

Comment: "This should only carry out the procedure (loading modal) when the distance calculated by Google is `over` the eDistance (50)". You will want to update that in the main body of your question.   Throw an alert box below `<script type="text/javascript">` and see if it is ever getting reached.